# How to settext that is in a fragment from a dialog fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I have a button that I want to settext as the date selected in my Dialog Fragment. I have tried using SharedPreferences but it wouldnt update unless fragment is restarted. I tried to look at the fragments lifecycle but I don't think it works the same way for a Dialog Fragment. SO my question is how do I set the text of the fragment from a dialog fragment initiated by the fragment

This is my code for my Dialog Fragment

```
public class DatePickerDialogTheme extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DatePickerTheme,this,year,month,day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        String string = (i1 + 1) + "/" +i2 + "/" + i;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("itemInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
        editor.putString("Birthday", string);
        editor.apply();


    }
}
```

And this is what I'm trying to change the text of in my fragment

```
mButton = view.findViewById(R.id.openCalendar);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerDialogTheme();
                dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Theme");
            }
        });
```

I also tried changing the text during onResume but still wouldnt work. I don't think it calls onResume when a DialogFragment opens up.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the other answers but this worked out best for me.

I just used

```
Button button = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
button.setText(string);
```

in my dialog fragment and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a proper way to do it:

**Define an interface for receiving result** (Notice that I use `getChildFragmentManager` to access the manager for child fragment, don't use call `getFragmentManager`

```
public interface DatePickerResultHandler {
    void onDatePicked(DatePickerDialogTheme dialog, int year, int month, int day);
}
```

**Make the outer `Fragment` implement the interface to receive the result**

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment implements DatePickerResultHandler {
    private Button mButton;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);
        mButton = view.findViewById(R.id.test_btn);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerDialogTheme();
                dialogFragment.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "Theme");
            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDatePicked(DatePickerDialogTheme dialog, int year, int month, int day) {
        String string = (year + 1) + "/" + month + "/" + day;
        mButton.setText(string);
    }
}
```

**Find the `DatePickerResultHandler` in `DatePickerDialogTheme`**. First try to cast it with the `Activity` or `Context` if you attach this dialog to the `Activity` only. If you attach it to parent fragment, cast it to `getParentFragment`

```
public class DatePickerDialogTheme extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
    private boolean isAttach;
    private DatePickerResultHandler mResultHandler;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        if (!isAttach) {
            findResultHandler(context);
            findResultHandler(getParentFragment());

            isAttach = true;
        }

        super.onAttach(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        if (!isAttach) {
            findResultHandler(activity);
            findResultHandler(getParentFragment());

            isAttach = true;
        }

        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    private void findResultHandler(Object parent) {
        if (mResultHandler == null && parent instanceof DatePickerResultHandler)
            mResultHandler = (DatePickerResultHandler) parent;
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int year, int month, int day) {
        if (mResultHandler != null)
            mResultHandler.onDatePicked(this, year, month, day);

        dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass your `TextView` object in the constructor of that fragment ad you are initializing it and then set the desired text. This could be a quick way around for what you are trying to do.

```
public class DatePickerDialogTheme extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
private TextView tv;

DatePickerDialogTheme(TextView tv){
    this.tv = tv;
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.DatePickerTheme,this,year,month,day);
}

@Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    String string = (i1 + 1) + "/" +i2 + "/" + i;
    tv.setText(string);
   }
```

}

And for the other part -

```
tv= parentViewOfTextView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
mButton = view.findViewById(R.id.openCalendar);
mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment dialogFragment = new DatePickerDialogTheme(tv);
            dialogFragment.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Theme");
        }
    });
```

Comment: do you have an example?